# Add an item to a list multiple times with list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a list in the following way:

```
lst = ['val1', 'val2', 'val3']

output = [item for it in lst]
```

...however, I would like to add an arbitrary number of each item to the list, not just one.

Something like this (if I wanted to add 3 elements each time to the list):

```
output = [item*3 for item in lst]
```

...so that if `lst` looks like this:

```
['val1', 'val2', 'val3']
```

...`output` looks like this:

```
['val1', 'val1', 'val1', 'val2', 'val2', 'val2'...]
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this (you'll have to change the code to suit your needs, obviously):

```
lst = ['val1', 'val2', 'val3']

output = [i for i in lst for x in range(3)]

print(output)
```

Output (formatted):

```
[
  'val1', 'val1', 'val1',
  'val2', 'val2', 'val2',
  'val3', 'val3', 'val3'
]
```

Change 3 to the number of times you want the item to repeat.

Answer (score 2):

How about just iterating through n x list?

```
li = ['val1', 'val2', 'val3']
n=3
print(sorted([el for el in li*n]))
```

Output:

```
['val1', 'val1', 'val1', 'val2', 'val2', 'val2', 'val3', 'val3', 'val3']
```